# SQL Query to sumproduct with grouped rows

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

I got the underlying data structure:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+-------+---------+------+------+------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| Row | Order | Extension | Position | Amount1 | Running number | Type  | Amount2 | Dim1 | Dim2 | Dim3 |      Text      | Additional Info | Articlegroup |
+-----+-------+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+-------+---------+------+------+------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|   1 |     1 | A         |       26 |       1 |             10 | Wood  |       1 | 1163 |   32 |   17 | Very good wood | Wood-1          | Wood Product |
|   2 |     1 | A         |       26 |       1 |             12 | Wood  |       1 | 1673 |   32 |   17 | Very good wood | Wood-1          | Wood Product |
|   3 |     1 | A         |       26 |       1 |             14 | Glass |       1 | 1163 |   32 |   17 | Very good wood | Wood-1          | Wood Product |
|   4 |     2 | A         |       29 |       1 |             16 | Wood  |       1 | 1673 |   32 |   17 | Very good wood | Wood-1          | Wood Product |
|   5 |     2 | A         |       29 |       1 |             48 | Wood  |       1 | 1356 |   32 |   17 | Very good wood | Wood-1          | Wood Product |
+-----+-------+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+-------+---------+------+------+------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I want two things:
1) I want another column that multiplies Amount1 * Amount2 * Dim1 /1000 (this might be a bit tricky due to point 2)

2) And I want the following output:

```
+-------+-------+----------------+------------+
| Order | Type  |      Text      | SumProduct |
+-------+-------+----------------+------------+
|     1 | Wood  | Very good wood |       2836 |
|     1 | Glass | Very good wood |       1163 |
|     2 | Wood  | Very good wood |       3029 |
+-------+-------+----------------+------------+
```

In summary, I want the rows to be grouped by Order, Type and Text and have a sum of the calculation done in point 1.

Point 1 would probably be realized using a subquery and just sum the rows. Row is a unique identifier, so we would probably need to include this in the subquery in order to create a relation.

Point 2 is something I am lost at. Text is a text field, so we might need to find a different way to group. When I tried grouping the rows, other columns were *affected* in the sense that you had to use them in the grouping as well - I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're looking for `SUM` with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT T.Order, T.Type, T.Text, SUM(T.Amount1*T.Amount2*T.Dim1) SumProduct
FROM YourTable T
GROUP BY T.Order, T.Type, T.Text
```

In your question, you mention to divide the sum by 1000, but I don't see that in your expected results so I left it out.

BTW, do you really have a column named `Order`?  That may need to be escaped as it's a reserved word in many databases.

Comment: DB design is in German, so I use the German word for Order. I will try your solution, but I think you are not allowed to group by text fields so will have to see how to handle this.

Comment: @Spurious -- which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Order
    ,Type
    ,Text
    ,SUM( Amount1 * Amount2 * Dim1 / 1000) SumProduct
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 
    Order
    ,Type
    ,Text;
```